# How to sign in Users into a Blazor serverside app via http

Tags: http, authentication, asp.net-core, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I am looking for a way to login users into a Blazor serverside App without using https. In production the app is beeing run behind a reverse proxy which will handle security.

When using the default Blazor App with authentication and accessing it via https everything is fine and I can login.

But when I remove `app.UseHsts();` and `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` from startup and access the app with http i can not login. There is no error message and I just get redirected to the startpage.

How can I make signing in work via http?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `ForwardedHeaders`. They tell the application what was the IP and protocol of a client

Add this to `Configure` method

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

If your proxy is not running on `localhost` you will also have to configure it's IP address

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.10.1"));
});
```

More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-a-reverse-proxy-server